# Continuity of an additive operator on Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

If operator $A: X \to Y$ satisfies $A(u+v)=Au+Av$ for all $u,v \in X$ and $A$ is continuous at one point of $X$ then $A$ is continous. Here $X$ and $Y$ denote Banach space.

I showed if $A$ is continuous at one point $x_0$ then $A$ is linear at $x_0$. However, I have some difficults to show that $A$ is linear on $X$. Maybe there is another way to proof that $A$ is countinuous operator?

Comment: If $x_n \to y$, then $x_n-y+x_0 \to x_0$. Now apply $A$ and use additivity to see that $A(x_n) \to A(y)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, it helped me a lot. Indeed, the operator is additive, not linear.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the definitions, $A$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$\lVert x - x_0\rVert < \delta \Rightarrow \lVert A(x) - A(x_0)\rVert < \varepsilon.$$

By the additivity of $A$, we have $A(x) - A(x_0) = A(x-x_0)$, so we can rephrase the condition

$$\lVert w\rVert < \delta \Rightarrow \lVert A(w)\rVert < \varepsilon$$

and here $x_0$ doesn't appear anymore, so it's clear that $A$ is continuous everywhere, since for all $x\in X$, we have

$$A(B_\delta(x)) \subset B_\varepsilon(A(x))$$

by the above.